# Accessing private variables in local with nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am creating a project in nuxt 3 and I am using `runtimeConfig`. I have done some research and found that I can create public variables (which are accessible on the client side) and private variables, which will not be exposed.

```js
runtimeConfig: {
  API_TOKEN_MAILERLITE: process.env.API_TOKEN_MAILERLITE,
  public: {
    API_BASE_MAILERLITE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_MAILERLITE_URL,
  },
},
```

The doubt I have is, for example, I have an `apiKey` to connect to an external service, this key I must put it as private because I don't want it to be exposed once it is in production and I must access it as a private variable:

```
runtimeConfig.API_TOKEN_MAILERLITE
```

But this way it is unreachable locally and I get it as undefined, so how can I populate this service if I can't access the token (unless I change the code by hand, but I try to avoid having to change the code every time I want to test it locally)

Comment: `private variables` are only accessible on the **server side**. You cannot have something private on the client side.

Comment: @kissu So how can I prove that it works in local?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Here are some answers that I gave on the subject already. They are for Nuxt2 but are still mostly totally relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access private variables from the Client side but for testing, you can use this :

```html
<script setup>
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
console.log("Runtime config:", config);
if (process.server) {
  console.log("API secret:", config.apiSecret);
}
</script>
```

You don't see API secret in your browser log but you can check it in your editor terminal

[image]

```js
console.log(runtimeConfig.apiSecret) // The private keys which are only available server-side
console.log(runtimeConfig.public.apiBase) //// Keys within public are also exposed client-side
```